# Migrations Folder Being Made in dist Folder

Tags: typescript, mikro-orm

I was messing around with the Mikro-ORM CLI and have been having a weird issue. I have done some research about how to properly set up Migrations in TypeScript and have set up my `package.json` and `mikro-orm.config.ts` to what I believe is correct.

```
# package.json
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "devDependencies": {devDependencies}
  "dependencies": {dependencies} 
  "mikro-orm": {
    "UseTsNode": true,
    "configPaths": [
      "./src/mikro-orm.config.ts",
      "./dist/mikro-orm.config.js"
    ]
  }
```

```
# mikro-orm.config.ts
export default {
    entities: [Hello],
    dbName: process.env.DB_NAME,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    type: 'postgresql' as const,
    migrations: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './migrations'), // path to the folder with migrations
        pattern: /^[\w-]+\d+\.[tj]s$/, // regex pattern for the migration files
    },
};
```

When `mikro-orm migration:create`, it creates the migrations folder in the dist folder, and generates the typescript file inside of it.

Obviously, this creates an error because its a typescript file.

From what I have seen, this should generate the migrations folder and .ts file in the src folder.

As a devDependency, I have installed ts-node. Not sure if that matters though.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of headache, I changed my files around and got a solution.

Removed the .ts file in configPaths

```
#package.json
  "mikro-orm": {
    "UseTsNode": true,
    "configPaths": [
      "./dist/mikro-orm.config.js"
    ]
  }
```

Removed the pattern and hard coded where I want the mutations to go.

```
#mikro-orm.config.ts
export default {
    entities: [Hello],
    dbName: process.env.DB_NAME,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    type: 'postgresql' as const,
    migrations: {
        path: './src/migrations', // path to the folder with migrations
    },
};
```